# Using Booleans in IEnumerator and coroutines

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

When the game starts the bool ismove is set to true whilst is supposed to be false so that when the coroutines starts, the bool ismove is later on set to true.
(The bool should be false but it automatically sets to true onstart)

Am I calling boolean correctly in this code? Bdw I set the bool public but did not assign it as true or false.

```
    public void Start()
    {
        rbody = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
        anim = GetComponent<Animator>();
        collectedTusker = 0;
        StartCoroutine(Countdown());
    }

    IEnumerator Countdown()
    {
        ismove = false;
        police.isfollowplayer = false;

        while (count > 0)
        {
            Countdowntext.text = count.ToString();

            yield return new WaitForSeconds(1f);

            count--;
        }

        Countdowntext.text = "GO!";

        yield return new WaitForSeconds(1f);

        //enable player and enemy movement
        ismove = true;
        police.isfollowplayer = true;

        Countdowntext.gameObject.SetActive(false);
    }
    public void FixedUpdate()
    {
        //onstart
        if (police.isfollowplayer == false)
        {
            ismove = false;
        }
        else
        {
            ismove = true;
        }

        //movement condition
        if (ismove == true)
        {
            anim.enabled = true;
            Movement();
            jump();
            
        }
        else
        {
            //no movement in y and x axis
            rbody.velocity = Vector2.zero;
            isdead = true;
        }    
    }
```

Comment: A side note: `if (police.isfollowplayer == false) { ismove = false; } else { ismove = true; }` can be replaced by `ismove = police.isfollowplayer;` because you set `ismove` to the same value as `police.isfollowplayer`. `if (ismove == true)` can be simplified as `if (ismove)`.

Comment: At the game start you start the coroutine `Countdown` which sets the variable to false after 1 second if `count` is 0.

Comment: count is not initialized there.. so the value is 0... another thing you are changing the value of ismove in the fixed update dont make any sence

Comment: how is it set to false because I declared it to be true?...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using `ismove` in `FixedUpdated` and in `Coroutine`.

When you call `StartCoroutine(Countdown());` it sets `police.isfollowplayer = false;` and your `FixedUpdate()` enters in a `if` that change `ismove` to `true`.

Try avoid using the same variable in `Coroutines` and `Updates` or create another `bool` to tell when is on `couroutines`.